# How to find elements of a large (1 million elements) array in another larger array (600 million elements)

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

I have a very large file (containing dbSNP ID), containing 1 million rows, each containing a single string, and another larger file (.vcf) containing 600 million rows, each containing 7-8 columns.

I want to find the first occurrence of each row of the smaller file in the larger file, making the brute force complexity of my program to be 1,000,000 * 600,000,000 times. I want a faster and less memory intensive way of doing this. I'm new to multiprocessing or parallel programming in python and I'm not sure how I can solve this without using either.

I've tried doing something like this for a smaller subset of both files, using the `numpy` and `pandas` libraries:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

BigFile = pd.Series(arrayOfRowsOfBiggerFile)
SmallFile = pd.Series(arrayOfRowsOfSmallerFile)
FinalList = SmallFile.map(lambda x: np.where(A==x)[0][0]).tolist()
```

This takes forever to execute and I'm sure can be handled well with python multiprocessing.

Comment: What about using database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you're actually performing a `join` operation: you want all the rows in the VCF whose key (RSID in this case) appears in your "smaller" file.  See docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

And your code would look something like this:

```
dbsnp = pd.read_csv('path/to/dbsnp', index_col='rsid', ...)
rsids_of_interest = pd.read_csv('path/to/smaller_file', ...)

subset_of_dbsnp = dbsnp.join(rsids_of_interest, how='inner', ...)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working for me for a small subset of the vcf file.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want just extract the subset of .vcf file based on variant list, you can

(**1**) use the solution suggested by @OronNavon. It should work at least with smaller files. With larger file sizes it could require a lot of computational resources, which isn´t necessarily a problem if you have access to cluster. If you are running it on home PC, you can run out of memory. You can work around it by reading the file on the fly, but it is still slow process. Also, you probably will lose a .vcf header with all meta-data so if you need that (or .vcf functionality), you should add it separately.

(**2**) split the .vcf file into chunks which you could run in parallel if you want. Though it will not be as efficient as it could be since you have just rsIDs and not locations in your smaller file.

(**3**) use [Plink](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/2.0/) which is a standalone package but it can do the job swiftly/efficiently. (This is what I would do.)